# How much does it cost on average a ticket for a World Cup Qualification game in South America?

Tags: football, world-cup

In South America (CONMEBOL Confederation) there is only one round of games where everyone plays twice with everyone.

My question is, how much did a ticket cost for the last qualifiers, for 2022 World Cup?

Couldn't find this information on the internet.

Even a specific game is fine, Argentina - Brazil would be great.